# Почему даггер2 синглтон работает не так как ожидается?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger2, dagger

Есть имплементация даггера в которой есть `AppSingletonModule`

```
@Module
class AppSingletonModule
{
    @PerApplication
    @Provides
    AppModel getAppModel()
    {
        return new AppModel();
    }
}
```

Я иcпользую `Scope` аннотацию `PerApplication'

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface PerApplication {
}
```

И ожидаю, что теперь обьект возвращаемый методом `getAppModel()` будет синглтоном.

Но нет в одном классе я использую напрямую этот обьект

```
@Inject
AppModel mAppModel;
```

И при дебаге вижу что это обьект `AppModel@6270`

И есть еще одно применение этого обьекта, но уже в графе самого даггера в другом модуле

```
@Provides
@Nullable
CallDetails getCallDetails(AppModel iAppModel)
{
    return iAppModel.getCallDetails();
}
```

Естественно я ожидаю, что получу как параметр обьект `AppModel@6270` , но почему то сюда прилетает обьект `AppModel@12959`

Что делаю не так?

Если, что то забыл спрашивайте

**EDIT**

Из `DynamicFormComponent` я получаю `AppModel` напрямую через инжект

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, AppSingletonModule.class})
public interface AppComponent
{
DynamicFormComponent getDynamicFormComponent();

CallSignatureComponent getCallSignatureComponent(CallSignatureModule iModule);

}
```

А вот компонент внутри которого я использую (как я думаю) тот же `AppModel`

```
@PerCallSignature
@Subcomponent(modules = {CallSignatureModule.class})
public interface CallSignatureComponent
{
void inject(CloseCallSignatureFragment iFragment);
}
```

И кстати еще я использую вот такой `ComponentHolder`

```
public ComponentsHolder init()
{
    if (mAppComponent == null)
    {
        AppModule appModule = new AppModule(mApp);
        mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(appModule).build();
    }

    return this;
}

public AppComponent getAppComponent()
{
    return mAppComponent;
}
```

И вот так я получаю `CallSignatureComponent`

```
public CallSignatureComponent getCallSignatureComponent(DrawingView mDvSignature, SignatureManagerListener mManagerListener, //
                                                        View iView, //
                                                        CallSignatureInterface iInterface, //
                                                        EWBaseFragment iFragment)
{
    CallSignatureModule module = new CallSignatureModule(mDvSignature, mManagerListener, iView, iInterface, iFragment);

    if (mCallSignatureComponent == null)
    {
        mCallSignatureComponent = getAppComponent().getCallSignatureComponent(module);
    }

    return mCallSignatureComponent;
}
```

Comment: покажите код компонента

Comment: @mit добавил код

Comment: пробовали добавить аннотацию `@PerApplication` к `getCallDetails`? у вас идет смешивание scoped/unscoped объектов.